# Android mysql php problem

Tags: php, mysql, android

I have an application which gets some data from a remote database.
I use PHP with the following code to connect to the data base.

```
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die( "no connection");
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = $_REQUEST['query'];
$q=mysql_query($query);

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $output[]=$e;
}
print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
```

I then connect via following java code

```
public void connect(ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
        result = "";
        InputStream is = null;

        String url = "http://'ipadress'/PhpProject1/EmptyPHP.php";

        //Get the content
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Connect", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        //Convert content toString
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            //result = replaceString(sb.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Connect", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

When i have done that I make a query through

```
public void query(String query){
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", query));
        connect(nameValuePairs);
    }
```

While this works great with the emulator there is a problem when using it on the phone.

Anyone has a clue why this is?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please describe the problem you're encountering.

Comment: I do not get any exceptions. A query goes straight through when using the emulator but when using the phone i just get a black display. Testing it i only have a TextView using the setText(queryResult) but nothing is showed on the phone

Comment: Print to logs what you got in result field and what you got in the response from php. I would remove the 8 as a parameter for the BufferedReader's constructor...

Comment: Found an error now: ERROR Connect Error in http connection java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out

Comment: @Bastaix can you navigate to the URL in the phone's browser?

Comment: @Bastaix: let me guess that server is in your private network?

Comment: That is right. Just for now. While developing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to connect your real device to the your private network to actually be able to access that server.

Easiest option would be a WiFi network in the same subnet as the server. Otherwise your phone won't be able to access the network as it is not public.